# Ajax call to a controller action result returns error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making an Ajax call to an ActionResult Method called Estatement.
Here is what I want to happen

1. if checkUser = false, there should be a redirection to a view
2. If checkuser is not false I want to return a Done as success and have my ajax
   code do something.

Right now I am unable to redirect to statement view and all I get is the alert from the error message (an error occured while trying to process this)

What do you think is wrong with this code?

```
    <div class="eStmnt">
        <div class="eStmntAd">
            <h3>Go Green!</h3>       
        </div>

        <p class="eStmntAffirm hide">Testing Testing</p>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".eStmnt").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Estatement","MyController")',
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(result) {               
                    if (result == "Done") {
                        $(".eStmntAffirm").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
                    }                   
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('An error occured while trying to process this');
                }
            });

        });

    </script>


     public ActionResult  Estatement()
            {

                bool checkUser = false;
                string result = string.Empty;

                if (checkUser == false)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Statement","MyProducts");       
                }

                result = "Done";

                return Json(result);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ajax is expecting a JSON, Your approach will not work. However you can try this instead

*Ajax success callback function*

```
success:function(data) {               
    //Do something when result is done
    if (data.status == "error" && data.redirectionUrl != "") {
        window.location.replace(data.redirectionUrl)
    }
    //Do something when result is done
    if (data.status == "success" && data.result == "Done") {
        $(".eStmntAffirm").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    }                   
},
```

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult  Estatement()
{       
    bool checkUser = false;
    string result = string.Empty;

    if (checkUser == false)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
        return Json(new {
            status = "success"
            redirectionUrl = urlHelper.Action("Statement","MyProducts")
        });
    }

    return Json(new {
        status = "success"
        result = "Done"
    });   
}
```

Comment: there is in the controller an UrlHelper available, just make `Url.Action(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your controller needs to return a JsonResult instead of an ActionResult

Ex: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

Comment: `ActionResult` is base class of `JsonResult` so no problem with it. See [MSDN DOCs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: you're right although I do prefer explicit return type.

Answer (score 0):

You are following a wrong approach...to handle this reqirent you need to follow this process...

First change your ajax call type to **"Get"** or if it is post then change your action method as following:

1.Change Ajax type to Post .

```
             [HttpPost]
             public ActionResult  Estatement()
               {

                bool checkUser = false;
                string result = string.Empty;
                 result = "Done";
                if (checkUser == false)
                {
                    result ="False";  
                }


                return Json(result,JsonAllowBehaviour.AllowGet);

            }
```

Then in success method of your ajax call write this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".eStmnt").click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Estatement","MyController")',
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(result) {               
                if (result == "Done") {
                    $(".eStmntAffirm").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
                }   
         // Condtion for redirect...
                  else
                 {
                 window.location='@Url.Action("Statement","MyProducts")';
                 }                 
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('An error occured while trying to process this');
            }
        });

    });
```